# how to search values in json field in sql (postgresql)

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

lets say i have a column named keyword with values like `['wood', 'grass', 'tree', 'plant']`,
now how do I query that if this array contains `wood` or `grass` or `both of them`

my solution (here I am using a text string and searching through it)

```sql
  select * from table where keywords_column ~* 'wood';
```

but it is limited to one word only.
It would be great if I would get solution in knex.js or Adonis Lucid

Comment: What is the data type?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid json

Answer (score 1):

I thought this might work, but I didn't test it:

```
select * from table where keywords_column ~* 'wood' or keywords_column ~* 'grass';
```

Comment: The `any()` operator only works with native arrays, not with JSON values containing arrays

Comment: I've used this method on fields of array type. Maybe he just needs an OR operation to search.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right, I removed the wrong answer. Thank you for the correction

Comment: That would also find rows with `grassland` or `woodpecker`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) `?|`

```
select * 
from the_table 
where keywords_column ?| array['wood', 'grass'];
```

This assumes that `keywords_columns` is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be  if you store JSON values). If it's not, you need to cast it `keywords_column::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=569b51124bc95b2caebc1883d0c174df)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

SELECT * from table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '(wood |grass |tree |plant )%';